# Why doesn't helveticaneue ultra light work in css?

Tags: css, fonts

I downloaded the font Helvetica Neue Ultralight .otf and wanted to implement it in my website through CSS. But I always get the Regular displayed. I looked and it was definitely Ultralight. Can you tell me a possible fix.

Thank you

Comment: you need a `ttf` format as well.

Comment: Are you sure the name is exactly "Helvetica Neue Ultralight"? If the name of the font is "Helvetica Neue", then you should use that, and add a `font-weight` style for good measure.

Comment: For example you've to write a like this. `body {
   font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
   font-weight: 300;
}`

Comment: Yes I added it like that and I converted it to ttf .> same result.

Comment: Can you point to the site where you downloaded the font?